# Why Doesn't PenAlignment.Inset Take Effect in User Control Drawing?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I made a custom movable control and have a problem with pixel calculation.

The control size is 100, 100 and Padding and Margin are both 0,0,0,0.

I thought subtracting pen width twice from control width (and height) would do but when I do 
Bottom and Right lines from DrawRectangle are clipped partially or totally, depending on the values of pen.Width and decrement factors of size.Width size.Height

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        var pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        pen.Width = 16;
        pen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
        var brush = Brushes.Aquamarine;
        var size = this.Size;
        size.Width -= (int)(pen.Width * 2);  
        size.Height -= (int)(pen.Width * 2);
        var rec = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rec);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rec);
    }
```

It seems like whole image outside the (90, 90) point is clipped no matter what value of pen.Width is chosen.

EDIT: I just found that the unwatned clipping doesn't happen when control.Location is set (0, 0).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MTC control;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        control = new MTC();
        control.Parent = panel1;
        control.Width = 100; control.Height = 200;
        //control.Left = 100; control.Top = 100;
        control.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        panel1.Controls.Add(control);
```

Comment: Painting is relative to the control's client area.  You must therefore use `var rec = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, size);`

Answer (score 0):

The line width can be variable but the exact 1 pixel line at the center of the whole thick line is drawn along the Rectangle. So you should calculate the Rectangle like this:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    pen.Width = 16;
    pen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset;
    var brush = Brushes.Aquamarine;
    var halfPenWidth = pen.Width/2;
    var rec = new RectangleF(Location, Size);
    rec.Width -= pen.Width;
    rec.Height -= pen.Width;
    rec.X += halfPenWidth;
    rec.Y += halfPenWidth;
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, rec);
    //Graphics.DrawRectangle does not support RectangleF directly
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rec.Left, rec.Top, rec.Width, rec.Height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by introducing another panel control and adding it to the *real* container.

```
public class Movable : Control
{
    public Panel ContainerPanel { get; set; }    
    public Movable(Point location, Size size) : base()
    {
        var pan = new Panel();
        pan.Margin = new Padding(0);
        pan.Padding = new Padding(0);
        pan.Location = location;
        pan.Size = size;
        this.ContainerPanel = pan;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.Size = size;
        pan.Controls.Add(this);
        pan.Height = size.Height; // Resize again after addition of 'content'
        this.movable = isMovable;
    }
    // codes for OnMouseDown, OnMouseUp, OnMouseMove, ...
}

public class MovableTest : Movable
{
    public MovableTest(Point location, Size size)
        : base(location, size) { }
    protected override void OnPaint(System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        // user drawing code comes here
    }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    MovableTest ctrl2;
    ctrl2 = new MovableTest(new Point(75, 50), new Size(100, 100));

    // add .ContainerPanel, NOT ctrl2 itself!
    this.Controls.Add(ctrl2.ContainerPanel); 
}
```